# curlでAmazon S3に画像をアップロードしたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aws, api, amazon-s3, carrierwave

curlコマンドでS3に画像をアップロードしたいです。
その場合curlコマンドはどのように指定してあげれば良いのか分からずにいます。

テストしたcurlコマンド

```
curl -v -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -X POST -d '{"user" : {"image" : "@test.jpg"}}' http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users.json
```

jsonのurlを叩いて、urlの欄にS3のURLが見えることがゴールなのですが、表示されません。
使用しているフレームワークはRailsで、carrierwaveというgemを使用しています。
適切なコマンドが知りたいです。
何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

追記

以下のコードでローカルにpostされた画像をS3に指定しています。
[参考リンク](http://qiita.com/ryo-ichikawa/items/a30dc626cba1ec909d57)

initializers/carrierwave.rb

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',
    :aws_access_key_id      => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY'],
    :aws_secret_access_key  => ENV['AWS_SECRET_KEY'],
    :region                 => s3-ap-northeast-1,
    :path_style             => true
}

config.fog_public     = true
config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=86400'}

case Rails.env
  when 'production'
    config.fog_directory = 'bucket'
    config.asset_host = 'http://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/buket'
  when 'development'
    config.fog_directory = 'bucket-dev'
    config.asset_host = 'http://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/bucket-dev'
  end
end
```

追記2
api/v1/users_controller.rb

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.json { render json: 'good', status: :created }
      else
        format.json { render json: 'bad', status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:image)
  end
end
```

Railsアプリにアップロードした画像をS3に保存（さらにcurlで動作テスト）したいです。
画像をcurlで送信、JSONフォーマットで受け取りが不明確のままでいます。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 質問の意図が読み取れずにおります。もう少し詳しく書いてもらえると回答出来るかもしれません。まず「http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users.json」とは何でしょうか？ curl で S3 にアップロード（PUT Obuject）したいのであれば S3のURLになると思うのですが localhostで動いているプログラムはどういったものなのでしょうか？

Comment: 一般にファイルアップロードは `multipart/form-data` と呼ばれる形式で行われるのでJSONではないと思うのですが、JSONで受け取るように実装したのでしょうか。それと `/api/v1/users.json` アクションのソースコードを書いてもらえませんか？

Comment: 追記しました。実際には'{"user" : {"name": "hoge"", "image" : "@test.jpg"}}'のようにテキストデータに加え、画像も送信したいのですが、画像に関してはどのようなコードを書く必要があるのでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Amazon S3 Authentication Tool for Curl](http://aws.amazon.com/code/128) を試してみてはどうでしょう。

Amazon S3の認証に必要なcurlのパラメータ指定をまとめてくれるPerlスクリプトらしいです。

実行例

```sh
./s3curl.pl \
  --id=[aws-access-key-id] \
  --key=[aws-secret-access-key] \
  --put=test.jpg \
  -- \
  http://s3.amazonaws.com/[bucket-name]/[key-name]
```

Comment: 質問の意図を勘違いしてたようです。Railsアプリにアップロードした画像をS3に保存（さらにcurlで動作テスト）したいということであればこの方法は使えませんね。

Comment: curlで動作テストしようと思っているのですが、ナンセンスだったりするのでしょうか。。動作テストの案があれば教えていただきたいです。

Comment: 手動テストであればcurlで直接APIを叩くのは悪くない選択だと思います。毎回テストするのが面倒で自動化させたい場合は、RSpecやMiniTestなどのテスト用フレームワークを導入することをオススメします。

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> curl -v -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -X POST -d '{"user" : {"image" : "@test.jpg"}}' http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users.json
> ```

これでは画像を送信していることにはなりません。`@test.jpg`という文字列がそのまま送信されています。

curlに@filenameと言う形式でファイルの中身を送信する機能はあるのですが、このような状況で適用する方法があるかはわかりません。

そもそも、JSONはテキストフォーマットなので、バイナリデータを送信するには向きません。

クライアント→Rails&CarrierWave→S3と言う構成のようですが、複数のレイヤで構成されているのであれば

- クライアントが意図したデータを送信しているか
- サーバ(アプリケーション)が意図した通りにデータを受け取っているか
- バックエンドストレージであるS3に意図したリクエストが飛んでいるか

など、各レイヤを切り分けて確認するとよいでしょう。